# Is there a way to find CPU power use specifically?

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, central-processing-unit, ipmitool

I have a few nodes running CentOS 7.6. With DCMI and ipmitool, I can obtain the power use of the entire node. Is there any way to determine how much power is being used by a CPU alone, preferably without root privileges?

Comment: You could try `turbostat` which is shipped with `kernel-tools`. Not sure how accurate that is, but it does provide `PkgWatt` which should reflect the CPU power usage.

Comment: You seem to have created 2 separate users here by mistake. You can get them merged by posting to https://meta.serverfault.com/ with links to both accounts and ask to get them merged. That way you will be able to edit your own question without waiting for approval.